# Can't connect to my sql instance via management studio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've created a google cloud vm with SQL server integrated

I tried to access my instance with windows login but no success, is there any step that im missing in the configuration? I don't see any details on how to retrieve this account or create a new sa acccount.